# Why the ground state of the Kiteav model almost a singlet?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information

The interaction strengths `J_x=J_y=J_z`.

I have checked by exact diagonalization.

Comment: If it weren't, it wouldn't be a spin liquid.

Comment: And what's your definition of the spin liquid?

Comment: For one thing, doesn't order magnetically.  By the way, what do you mean by "almost"?

Comment: The system has large probability in total spin S=0 subspace. I mean, is there any explanation just like the Heisenberg model?

Comment: What would be the "simple" explanation for the Heisenberg model?  AFAIK this is a non-trivial result due to Lieb and Mattis.

Comment: Yes, I discovered this fact by numerical tests. However, a mathematical proof could be non-trivial. Maybe, we could introduce Kiteav's representation for spins to get a voug picture of this problem.